# How to build an empty label with Rails' FormHelper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-helpers

I am trying to build a label without any value using [Rails' label helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-label) (don't ask why; I need it for some CSS3 magic).

This does *not* work:

```
<%= f.label :last_name, "" %>
```

(Rails overrides the blank string with the label value anyway.)

Neither does this:

```
<%= f.label :last_name, nil %>
```

This *does* work but seems cumbersome:

```
<%= f.label :last_name do %>
    <%= "" %>
<% end %>
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Have you tried using `label_tag` ?

Comment: Not in this case, because I am dealing with a form object `f` here.

Comment: Try something like `label_tag "#{f.class}[last_name]", '' '`

Answer (score 3):

I don't like the syntax, but it works.

```rb
f.label :last_name, "&nbsp;".html_safe
```

Answer (score 2):

FYI: https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/bootstrap_form/commit/f4d76b51

```
label: "&#8203;".html_safe
```

or

```
label: "<span></span>".html_safe
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding it to translations ?

You can add it inside `en.yml` file and set value for this label to be empty

```
helpers:
  label:
    model_name:
      last_name: ""
```

This will set label for `model_name.last_name` as `""`

Comment: Thanks but this is not possible since I need the *real* localized label in another place as well.